# In OSX, why don't my Panasonic and Olympus DNG files have thumbnail icons?

Tags: dng, os-x, thumbnails

I've shot with Nikon, Olympus, and Panasonic so I'm familiar with all their proprietary RAW formats that each uses. I'd like to convert all my RAW files to DNG and then use that on import into LR going forward.

I noticed that the DNG files from the Panasonic or Olympus images don't display a thumbnail in my finder folders (Mac OS X) so I tried some experiments:

I used the "convert to DNG" function in LR for some RAW files from each of the 3 cameras. Only the images taken with the Nikon D5300 show a thumbnail image in my finder folder. The Oly and Panny shots only display the DNG icon.

Next I used the "export to DNG" function thinking that might make the thumbnail available but it was just the same. I would like to be able to see the images in my finder folders and also be able to open them to view in "preview" but only the Nikon converted DNGs will open in preview and not the Panny or Oly DNGs.

Am I doing something wrong in the preferences? I've attached a screen shot of my preferences settings for DNG in LR and the thumbs that I'm seeing in my finder folders.

[image: settings for converting to DNG][image: Nikon converted DNG thumbnail in finder][image: Panasonic converted thumbnail in finder][image: Panasonic RAW thumbnail in fider]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that this is all solved by upgrading my OS to 10.10.2, Yosemite. I did that on my MacBook Air and all DNG converted files show up in finder and open in Preview, it didn't matter whether they were RW2, ORF, or NEF. The problem was obviously that OS 10.8, Mountain Lion, couldn't preview the DNG thumbnails from the RW2 and ORF formats. Thanks everyone for your input.

Answer (score 0):

Mac doesn't support every RAW format unfortunately. Here is a list of cameras that are supported:

[Mavericks](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201071)
[Yosemite](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203088)

If your Panasonic and Olympus aren't listed, this could be why your Nikon images show.

Several posts suggest that that Apple supports some conversions, but others need to have 
"Convert to Linear Image" option disabled in the DNG conversion settings.

Personally, I use Lightroom to view images, as finder is hit or miss as you have seen.

Comment: "Mac doesn't support every RAW format unfortunately." That doesn't seem to be the issue here as I can see all thumbnail previews in finder for ALL types of RAW files (just added a thumbnail of a Pan RAW). The only ones not displayed are the DNGs from Panny and Oly. 

At times, it is much faster/easier to use finder for certain tasks. 

I'll look into "convert to linear image" option. Thanks.

Comment: I'm running 10.8 (ML) and the list for that OS supports RAW for the GH2, GH3, and Oly Em-1 so that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I don't see where the "convert to linear image" option is available to select or deselect in either the convert to DNG dialog or in the LR preferences. Do you know where that might be found?

Comment: In Adobe DNG converter, Linear option is available under 'custom' in Compatibility

Comment: My only choices in Compatibility are all the versions of Camera Raw as seen in the screen shot of the DNG converter above. I don't see "custom". Same thing in the LR preferences. I'm using a subscription to CC/LR so it is the latest version available. 

On the Adobe LR forum, one person thought it might have to do with the way mirrorless cameras do their own profiles in-camera rather than in LR. Since the problem only is with my mirrorless cameras and not with any others, that might be the snag.

Comment: I found what you were referring to in deselecting the linear option - it is only available in the separate Adobe DNG Converter app, not in the LR converter that I was using. I tried using the Adobe app with those settings and the same result; it converts the images but no preview thumb. 

I've gotten some replies to this on the Adobe forum and others have had the same issue with m4/3 camera profiles that are not playing nicely with Apple so I've decided to not convert until they address this, at least for now. 

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Someone who replied to my post in DPReview has no issues with his Olympus files converted but he is running Yosemite and I think maybe the problem I'm having is that I'm running Mountain Lion. Time to upgrade but I've been stalling until I can buy some updated programs that won't run in Yosemite.

Comment: I just updated my MB Air to Yosemite and all the DNG files show thumbs in finder and open in Preview so, mystery solved.

Comment: @pcgould Maybe write that up as an answer and accept it?